# Parameterizing SVG text rotation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, symbology, svg, parameters

In QGIS, I made some custom SVG symbols for a project I’m working on and I’ve had success using parameters to control fill, stroke, and stroke width. However, I have text in the symbols that I would like to rotate to face straight up no matter what angle the whole symbol is facing.

So far the text object I’ve been working with has a matrix transformation applied to it.

```
transformation=“matrix(a,b,c,d,e,f)”
```

I tried applying a second transformation just for the rotation with no luck.

```
transformation=“matrix(a,b,c,d,e,f)” transformation=“rotate(param(textangle))”
```

I then tried adding a rotation to the existing transformation

```
transformation=“matrix(a,b,c,d,e,f) rotate(param(textangle))”
```

After this, I tried just using the rotate tag, which is supposed to rotate each character in the text independently

```
transformation=“matrix(a,b,c,d,e,f)” rotate=“param(textangle)”
```

I also tried adding the rotation to the group consisting of the circle and the text inside it with no luck.

[image: Complex SVG with rotate added to the the containing the circle and text inside it]

I haven’t had a ton of time to play with it beyond that but I’m wondering is this just a limitation in the way that QGIS renders the SVG?

Just to test I made a standalone SVG with only one path and no other transformations to see if I could use a parameter to make it rotate.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg width="300" height="300" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 300 300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill="param(fill) #ff00ff" stroke="param(outline) #ff00ff" transform="rotate(param(angle)" d="m150 128.31-21.691 43.382h43.382z"/>
</svg>
```

The original image is a triangle with the point facing up. As you can see in this image I have added the expression with no change to the symbol.

[image: Simple SVG with rotate parameter]

Comment: Just to be sure: 1) do you have a non parametrizable SVG that works with matrix + rotation? 2) Have you followed the documentation and added an expression for the parameter?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by number one but I tested it with an SVG consisting of only a single path with no other transformations applied to it with no change in results. I updated the question to reflect this. In regards to number 2, yes I have added an expression for the parameter. I have added screenshots to the question just in case I'm doing something wrong however.

Comment: Insted of adding the text to the SVG symbol, would using a label be an option?

Comment: I thought about that but I’m not sure how much effort it would be to make sure the label stays in the center of that circle. These symbols are ideally going to be reused for multiple amplifiers in the same configuration so it’s not like I just have to line the label up with the symbol once. There could be 50 amplifiers in this same configuration but in different orientations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/40596/files#diff-a1f1db50aa4de9272401b6ec9b3b258c2273b5811ed205e45593b84f6af29c5bR605
[image]

QGIS is actually looking for the whole node. So instead of

`transform="rotate(param(angle)"`

do

`transform="param(rotation)"`

and have `rotation` defined with an expression as `'rotate(30)'` or `'rotate('||my_field||')'`

I created a modification of the QGIS docs: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/pull/8596

Comment: Using the parameter that way actually seems pretty obvious now that you mention it! I should be able to test it with my project tomorrow. I’ll update with my results.